# how to access query string in wordpress?

Tags: wp-query, functions, filters, query-variable, query-string

There are several ways I have seen this question worded, so I tried to make mine generic.

Let's say I go to this page:

`example.com/page/?utm_source=test&s=test&page=12`

`get_query_var('utm_source')` returns nothing.

`$_GET` returns `Array ( [s] => test [page] => 12 )`.

`$_GET` returns `Array ( [utm_source] => )` from `example.com/page/?utm_source` (key only, no value), which I really don't understand.

I've done this in `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "utm_source";
    return $vars;
}
```

...just like ye olde codex says, so I would expect to be able to access `utm_source` through `get_query_var('utm_source')`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there another plugin that would possibly catch that `utm_source` parameter before your own code runs?

Comment: Perhaps, but my question is more about the fact that I'm going by the book as far as I know, with unexpected results.

Comment: Thinking about it, if it's not in the `$_GET` something must be removing it really early. Maybe there is something in your Apache/PHP install that will remove those `utm_...` early on. What I would try is to write the `$_GET` variable in the `index.php` (so super early on) and also search all the files in your plugins for the string `utm_` to see whether other plugins handle those variables.

Comment: I had already looked & checked again for anything server-side which might be interfering. No plugins are being used. Also, see edit to original question: `utm_source` key is in `$_GET` when `utm_source` is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to my general question has a very specific answer, and I found the answer by running across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945461/1122373) to more or less the same problem. Basically GoDaddy hosting does something special to `utm_`-type query strings. Tech support could provide no detail.

In case anyone else runs across this, it looks like something mysterious happens to the standard Google Analytics query strings such as `utm_source`. Example: `utm_source` will not show up in `$_GET` (much less using `get_query_var`), but `utm__source` (2 underscores) is just fine.

Comment: *Tech support could provide no detail.* Wow, that sounds frustrating. Glad you were able to track it down, though.

Comment: Ah, so it is before you hit your PHP. They may have a form of proxy server and the proxy-ing server will removes `utm_*` variables before your server is hit. I would never have thought of such done by a hosting company. On my end I'm using DigitalOcean and get everything through "no problem." (except that includes all spam/hacker hits too.)

Comment: It appears to be not just `utm_*`; `utm___source` (multiple underscores) works fine! But why?